# how to get month number instead of string using strftime()

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

`strftime('%m',myDate)` gives a string( `01-12` according to the [doc](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)). How do i convert this to a number so that i can use it in a where clause?

For example,
I expect the below condition to be true. But since `strftime()` returns the string `"12"` instead of the number `12`, it is false :

```
WHERE strftime('%m','2104-12-22') = 12
```

Answer (score 2):

use :

```
CAST(strftime('%m',myDate) AS INTEGER)
```